# How do I get the values of an array of select tags in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I have a dynamic form that adds and removes elements wherein several of the fields are select items.

```
<div style="float: left; padding: 6px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
  <input class="input-sm" name="txt_description[]" type="text" placeholder="Description" /></div>
<div style="float: left; padding: 6px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
<?php  echo $this->tag->select(array("opt_bill_type[]",
                                ReferenceVal::find("REF_CD = 'BILL_TYPE'"),
                                "useEmpty"  =>  false,
                                "using" => array("VALUE", "VALUE"),
                                "class" => "input-sm",
                                ));
                        ?>
 </div>
```

I am able to access the value for the array of input="text" elements but I cannot do so for `<select>` fields

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Can you add to the question the output HTML produced by your php script.